# Showing dynamic value in translated string

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Im using Angular Translate, specifically the filter translate with dynamic values (https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.filter:translate). I want to translate a string and include a dyncamic value. In my translations file I have:

```
products:
    searchResults: "Search results for {{ searchTerm }}"
```

And in my jade template:

```
.bg-info(ng-show='productVM.search') {{ 'products.searchResults' | translate:'{searchTerm: productVM.search}' }}
```

So when I type, the controller property search contains the string and the div shows, except the result is:

```
Search results for
```

If I was to replace 'productVM.search' with 'test', it would work:

```
Search results for test
```

It appears that angular translate doesnt like if the value pass to it is dynamic. Anyway around this?

Comment: you could maybe ngrepeat over the searchTerms